# Why do we assume that $A \subset (0,1)$ when proving that $N \subset A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set and $m(A) > 0$, then there exists $N \subset A$ that is non-measurable.

In some proof, they start by assuming that $A \subset (0,1)$ and it seems that they imply that this is sufficient. How to reason out mathematically and intuitively that this is indeed true?

Comment: If $A$ is a measurable set with positive measure, then $A\cap(n,n+1)$ has positive measure for some $n\in\mathbb Z$. So it's clear that we can assume, without loss of generality, that $A\subseteq(n,n+1)$ for some integer $n$. I guess your question is why we can assume w.l.o.g. that $n=0$?

Comment: Yes, why is it?

Comment: As @bof said, you can assume without loss of generality that $A\subset(n,n+1)$. Then you can do the proof with $A'=A-n\subset(0,1)$ whose measure is positive, which yields a non-measurable set $N'\subset A'$. Then you take $N=N'+n$ which is a non-measurable subset of $A$. So it is indeed sufficient to suppose $A\subset(0,1)$. Basically the key ingredient here is that applying a translation to a set preserves its (non-)Lebesgue-measurability, and the Lebesgue measure is invariant by translation.

Answer (score 0):

Measurability is translation- and scaling-invariant. That is, given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, if we define
$$\begin{align*}
aE &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x = az \text{ for a } z \in E \} \\
E+b &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x = b+z \text{ for a } z \in E \}
\end{align*}$$
then if $E$ is measurable, so are $aE,E+b$ with $\mu(E) = \mu(E+b)$ and $\mu(aE) = a \cdot \mu(E)$. This is, in principle, easy to show: take your coverings by boxes from the definition of (outer) measure, and apply an analogous transformation to them.

So, suppose $V$ is non-measurable. Then $aV$ and $V+b$ necessarily are also non-measurable, for any $a,b$ with $a \ne 0$. (Otherwise, the sets $\frac 1 a (aV)$ and $(V+b)-b$ will be non-measurable scalings/translations of measurable sets.)

So, it is enough to start a non-measurable $V$ in $(0,1)$, and shift/scale $V$ or copies thereof to wherever in $\mathbb{R}^1$ that they're needed and so that they're within $A$.

One can then extend this in the obvious manner for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general, to achieve even more generality.